# Facebook App info = unapproved

Tags: android, facebook

I am trying to setup a Facebook app. Im using it for sharing and invites on my Android app.

I made a request to use "publish_actions" on Android, and it got approved.
But for some reason, on developers.facebook.com, when editing the app, under AppDetails, next to AppInfo on top is a icon that says "Unapproved" when hovered over.

On dashboard, i can see the green circle that says "Live and available to all users".

Invite notifications don't seem to be received (although they do get sent) so I'm thinking that this could be the problem?

How can i request approval of my AppInfo?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about Facebook apps.

Answer (score 2):

the app info is unapproved because the app doesn't have the numbers to get featured in the [appcenter](https://www.facebook.com/appcenter). When people go crazy about your app, and your installs grow, and the app usage too, you'll have the possibility to submit your app info for review. For notifications we need the code. It's a totally unrelated problem.